# there is a bug that is ons-tab not work in my program

Tags: onsen-ui

My code as follows， when I click tab button "Ratios", it does not work,but when I click "Notes", it works.Actually,when I change the sequence of ons-template， such as ons-template sequence is "price.html","notes.html","ratios.html",the result is  when I click tab button "notes", it does not work,but when I click "Ratios", it works.
Anybody knows the reason?

```
 <ons-page ng-controller="myPortfoliosController">
    <ons-toolbar class="DCF">
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button style="color:white;"></ons-back-button>
        </div> 
        <div class="center" style="font-size:22px;" >My Portfolios</div>
    </ons-toolbar>        
    <ons-tabbar  position="top">
        <ons-tab page="price.html"  active="true">Price</ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="ratios.html">Ratios</ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="notes.html" >Notes</ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-template id="price.html">
        <ons-page ng-controller="portPrice">
            <div class="row" style="height:20px;background-color: #144A88;color:white;font-size: 14px;width: 100%;padding-left: 10px;">            
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:35%;">Stock Symbol</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;">Current</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:25%;">Purchased</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;">Change</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="portfolio in portfoliosList">
                <div class="portname_{{portfolio.backgroundColor}}">{{portfolio.portname}}</div>
                <div ng-repeat="portfolioStock in portfolio['detail']">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:40%;border-bottom:1px dashed #c0c0c0;">{{portfolioStock.symbol}}</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;border-bottom:1px dashed #c0c0c0;">{{portfolioStock.price}}</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;border-bottom:1px dashed #c0c0c0;">{{portfolioStock.in_price}}</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;border-bottom:1px dashed #c0c0c0;color:{{portfolioStock.font_color}}">{{portfolioStock.gain_p}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="ratios.html">
        <ons-page  ng-controller="portRatios">
            <div class="row" style="height:20px;background-color: #144A88;color:white;font-size: 14px;width: 100%;padding-left: 10px;">            
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:35%;">Stock Symbol</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:25%;">P/E(ttm)</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;">P/S</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="width:20%;">P/B</div>
            </div>  
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="notes.html">
        <ons-page  ng-controller="portNotes">
            <div class="row" style="height:20px;background-color: #144A88;color:white;font-size: 14px;width: 100%;padding-left: 20%;">            
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2" style="width:45%;">Stock Symbol</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2" style="width:55%;">User Notes</div>
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Can you also post the `tabbar` and `tab` code? Without it it's hard to say. Also, there is a `</ons-page> ` tag at the end which has never been opened.

Comment: I post my tabbar and tab code now.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to wrap everything inside an `ons-page` element and that's wrong. You can never wrap `ons-template` inside `ons-page`, just the opposite is fine.

To fix your app, just remove the last `</ons-page>` tag and add it immediately after `</ons-tabbar>`, you will have a main page like this:

```html
<ons-page ng-controller="myPortfoliosController">
    <ons-toolbar class="DCF">
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button style="color:white;"></ons-back-button>
        </div> 
        <div class="center" style="font-size:22px;" >My Portfolios</div>
    </ons-toolbar>        
    <ons-tabbar  position="top">
        <ons-tab page="price.html"  active="true">Price</ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="ratios.html">Ratios</ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="notes.html" >Notes</ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I move three ons-templates to outside of main page,it also not work.

Comment: @Miao the issue is probably related with the `ng-controller="myPortfoliosController"`, I made a CodePen example removing it and it works, you probably should put it in another point of your app. Here is the working example: [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/yYoKZo)

Comment: Sorry ，I cannot get your point.Can you say some of the details?

Comment: Add `ng-controller="myPortfoliosController"` inside the `body` tag and let me know if something happens. Have you seen the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/yYoKZo) example? It works fine.

Comment: If there is an error message in the console, please report it.

Comment: Yes I see it.But I don't know why, when I run these code in the monaca,It also does not work.http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdvLzb, In the monaca, when I click Ratios,alert(123123) is does not work.

Comment: I degbug it in a android platform, it shows that there is a error,cannot find the ratios.html.

Comment: I don't know what to say, the code example I provided works, I also tested in my android device.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solve my problem by separating different page in the different html document.